# laravel query - join 2 table and groupBy same ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 table like this

table Base_infos

```
| id |base_name|
+----+---------+
|  1 |   name1 |
|  2 |   name2 |
|  3 |   name3 |
|  4 |   name4 |
|  5 |   name5 |
|  6 |   name6 |
```

table Base_types

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id |  base_id|     type|
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       2 |       0 |
|  3 |       3 |       1 |
|  4 |       4 |       0 |
|  5 |       5 |       1 |
|  6 |       6 |       1 |
|  7 |       6 |       0 |
```

and my query like this

```
$datas = DB::table('base_infos')
    ->select('base_infos.id as id', 'base_infos.base_name', 'base_types.type')
    ->join('base_types', 'base_infos.id', '=', 'base_types.id')
    ->groupBy('base_infos.id')
    ->get();
```

but the data return only first record of table base_types like this

- 'id': '6'
- 'base_name': 'name6'
- 'type': '0'

How can I show all type in one line ? I'm using Laravel 7 and mysql

Comment: Your join condition also seems wrong.

Comment: What's the point of the base_id column? (hint)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `groupBy('base_infos.id')`?
Isn't id unique, if so you don't need that grouping.

Comment: I need to combine row where id of base_infos table is the same so that is why I use groupBy

Answer (score 0):

Do you manage relations in the model or not?
If you have set the relations in the model, you can use this method to merge / GroupBy between relations
I used this method and it worked

```
// Displays the most purchased items [ TAMPIL ]
    $most_item_buy = Item::with(["item_orders" => function($query) {
        $month = date('m');
        $year = date('Y');

        $query->selectRaw('*, sum(item_order_details.quantity) as total_item');
        $query->groupBy('pivot_item_id');
        
        $query->where("order_status", "=", "FINISH");
        $query->whereMonth("item_orders.created_at", $bulan);
        $query->whereYear("item_orders.created_at", $tahun);

    }, "item_images"])
        ->withTrashed()
        ->get();
```

Comment: I did have relations in model, thanks. I solved my problem